# SIGABRT error in spoj

Tags: sigabrt

I tried the prime generator problem in spoj with the following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t,n1,k;
    int *x;
    cin >> t;
    int *m = new int[t];
    int *n = new int[t];
    for(int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        cin >> m[i] >> n[i];
        if(i != 0)
            if(n[i] > n[i-1])
                n1 = n[i];
    }
    x = new int[n1];
    x[2] = 2;
    for(int i = 3; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
            x[i] = 0;
        else
            x[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 3; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        if(x[i] != 0)
        {
            for(int j = i + i; j < n1; j = j + i)
                x[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        k = n[i];
        for(int j = m[i]; j <= k; j++)
        {
            if(x[j] != 0)
                cout << x[j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I got an runtime error (SIGABRT).
Please help me out. I'm fairly new to this, so a little bit of kindness would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `x = new int[n1];`. `n1` can be as big as `10^9`, and you can't declare an array this big in size. You can use **Sieve of Eratosthenes** to solve this problem. Read about it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes